# Returning previous business day instead of currentDate with fastDateFormat

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch, java-batch

I currently have the below code utilized for retrieving current date in spring batch. Is there a way to implement a similar solution, but instead, returning the previous business day instead of the currentDate?

```
<bean id="fastDateFormat" class="org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat"
    factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyyMMdd" />
</bean>

<bean id="currentDate" class="java.util.Date" factory-bean="fastDateFormat"
    factory-method="format">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.Date" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Before digging into how to technically do this, why would you need to create a bean of type `Date` with the current date (or previous day date)? This should be a runtime information and not a static bean definition. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Using [natty](https://github.com/joestelmach/natty) you can parse natural language date expressions like "yesterday" or "24 hours before now" to generate a java.util.Date object.